# Order by Progressive Number

Tags: python

I've recently started python, and I'm looking for a way to order a progressively number

Example, as I work with accounting, a basic balance sheet structure start as:

```
1 - Asset
1.1 - Asset short term
1.1.1 - xxxxxxxxx
11102312313 - Cash (Accounting account)
```

and that repeats for Liabilities (2) , Expenses (3) Revenue (4)

How can I order like the example above, cause if I order direct on Excel it would like that :

```
1
2
3
4
100000000
1.1
1.1.1
etc..
```

But I do need the to list as the first example

Comment: Is this python or excel? In python you can give a key function of tuple(int(x) for x in data.split('.')) to sorted()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nice! This isn't trivial for a Python beginner, yet pretty manageable. Won't do your work here, but set you on the right path:

- Let's assume you have a list of strings, `["1 - Asset", "1.1 - Asset short term", ...]`
- You'll want to sort that list ([tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)), so you need to use Python's built-in `sorted()` on that list
- But `sorted` will do an alphabetical sorting by default, which doesn't seem to be what you want
- To teach it other sorting methods, you need to implement a `key`, i.e. some class (or more generally, type) or function return value that can be compared (like with `<`, `>`, `>=`) correctly. For example, a string that starts with a pattern like `*.*` should always be `>` than a string that starts with a plain number like 10000000.
- Then it's just `sortedlist = sorted(inputlist, key=accountingkey)`

A typical key class might look like

```py
def extract_ordinal_from_string(string):
    hyphenposition = string.find(" -")
    if hyphenposition < 0:
         raise Exception(f"Row doesn't contain ' -', can't be sorted: {string}")
    return string[:hyphenposition]


class accounting_key:
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.key = extract_ordinal_from_string(string)
        self.dot = "." in self.key

    def __lt__(other):
        """
        lt: less-than (<) comparison operator
        """

        otherkey = extract_ordinal_from_string(other)
        otherdot = "." in otherkey

        if otherdot and self.dot:
            """"
            Both contain dots.
            Lets put them both in tuples, compare these:
            (1,1,0) < (1,2)
            """
            selftuple = tuple(int(substring) for substring in self.key.split("."))
            othertuple = tuple(int(substring) for substring in otherkey.split("."))
            return selftuple < othertuple

        if not self.dot and not otherdot:
            return int(self.key) < int(otherkey)

        if self.dot and not otherdot:
        ### And so on, up to you to implement
```

Comment: Tks Marcus, I'm going to start studyng this and I'll update my progresse here, thank you to set me on right path